# Blender crashes upon opening

Tags: error, windows

I installed Blender (2.83) for the first time on my new Custom Built PC.
Windows 10, Intel i7, x 64bit and opened double clicking the .exe file, a grey screen appears as well as a black dialogue box that closes shortly after.
I tried to open it using the Powershell window and got this as my error message.

*PS C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.83> ./blender.exe
GPUTexture: create : TEXTURE_1D, RGBA8, w : 1, h : 0, d : 0, comp : 4, size : 0.00 MiB
GPUTexture: texture alloc failed. Likely not enough Video Memory.
Current texture memory usage : 0.00 MiB.
GPUTexture: create : TEXTURE_2D, RGBA8, w : 1, h : 1, d : 0, comp : 4, size : 0.00 MiB
GPUTexture: texture alloc failed. Likely not enough Video Memory.
Current texture memory usage : 0.00 MiB.
GPUTexture: create : TEXTURE_3D, RGBA8, w : 1, h : 1, d : 1, comp : 4, size : 0.00 MiB
GPUTexture: texture alloc failed. Likely not enough Video Memory.
Current texture memory usage : 0.00 MiB.
found bundled python: C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.83\2.83\python
GPUTexture: create : TEXTURE_2D, RGBA8, w : 1515, h : 26, d : 0, comp : 4, size : 0.15 MiB
GPUTexture: texture alloc failed. Likely not enough Video Memory.
Current texture memory usage : 0.15 MiB.
GPUTexture: create : TEXTURE_1D_ARRAY, R8, w : 16384, h : 1, d : 0, comp : 1, size : 0.02 MiB
GPUTexture: texture alloc failed. Likely not enough Video Memory.
Current texture memory usage : 0.02 MiB.
Error   : EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION
Address : 0x00007FF7F5A90CC0
Module  : C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.83\blender.exe
PS C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.83>*

I've made sure that my graphics card drivers and windows PC drivers are all up to date. Running Blender as an Administrator doesn't work either. I have searched through forum posts for solutions but haven't found any that fix my issue yet.

Hoping to get some light shed on the problem.

Thanks

Comment: What kind of GPU do you have?

Comment: I have Nvidia GeForce GTX 1660 SUPER

Comment: Yeah, that's weird. Definitely supported - but it seems like blender can't access your video ram for some reason.

Comment: There seems to have been others with this issue and it has been reported. Some users found success by changing windows power saving settings (or doing otherwise) in order to "force" windows to use an integrated intel gpu to open blender. Full post is here, I'm still combing through it - https://developer.blender.org/T72098

Comment: Filtering through the post, I saw the advice of changing the dialog box for Blender from 'System Default' to 'Power Saving' in Graphic Settings and it worked! I am not sure why though.. But blender is up and running for the first time yet!

Comment: Yeah, I saw that too. Glad you got it working.

Comment: yeah me too! Thanks so much for your help brother![